# Checkstyle Plug-in Eclipse Error on Fedora

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

I am fairly new with Eclipse plug-ins and have added Checkstyle Plug-in 6.11.1 through the Eclipse Marketplace and this appears to have worked correctly, in that I am able to right click on the project and perform some actions using Checkstyle, as well as it appearing in *Window -> Preferences*. However when I select *Checkstyle -> Check code with checkstyle* I get the following error:

`An internal error occurred during: "Checking files...".
Could not initialize class net.sf.eclipsecs.core.builder.CheckerFactory`

I have also had a look into the error log and came across other issues that may provide more insight but from my searching I cannot seem to find anything of similar nature. I have added the stack trace from the error.
I am using Eclipse Mars.1 on Fedora 23.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
!ENTRY net.sf.eclipsecs.core 4 0 2015-11-07 17:38:56.578
!MESSAGE Checkstyle-Plugin: Plug-in "net.sf.eclipsecs.core" was unable to instantiate class "net.sf.eclipsecs.core.projectconfig.filters.NonSrcDirsFilter".
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "net.sf.eclipsecs.core" was unable to instantiate class "net.sf.eclipsecs.core.projectconfig.filters.NonSrcDirsFilter".
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:188)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.projectconfig.PluginFilters.<clinit>(PluginFilters.java:102)
at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.projectconfig.ProjectConfigurationFactory.createDefaultProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationFactory.java:142)
at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.projectconfig.ProjectConfigurationFactory.loadFromPersistence(ProjectConfigurationFactory.java:165)
at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.projectconfig.ProjectConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationFactory.java:81)
at net.sf.eclipsecs.ui.properties.CheckstylePropertyPage.setElement(CheckstylePropertyPage.java:172)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.RegistryPageContributor.createPage(RegistryPageContributor.java:161)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.PropertyPageNode.createPage(PropertyPageNode.java:57)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1300)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.createPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:355)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.showPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1187)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.showPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$9$1.run(PreferenceDialog.java:675)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$9.selectionChanged(PreferenceDialog.java:670)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:877)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:874)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1243)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$5.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1269)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:265)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$5(OpenStrategy.java:259)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1$2.run(OpenStrategy.java:440)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3794)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3433)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PropertyDialogAction.run(PropertyDialogAction.java:157)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.ProjectPropertyDialogAction.run(ProjectPropertyDialogAction.java:78)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4481)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1329)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3819)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3430)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/core/JavaModelException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaModelException cannot be found by net.sf.eclipsecs.core_6.11.1.201510102004
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:389)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
at    org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 71 more
```

Comment: This isn't so much an answer as a work around but I found that Eclipse now has its own installer and reinstalling Eclipse using this removed these problems. Hopefully that helps anyone who comes across the same issue.